# Pythonic way to pass optional parameter by variable name

Tags: python

I'm sorry if the question is a bit unclear, I'm not sure how to phrase it.

I'm working with a package that has a function with a number of optional parameters. Say there are three parameters: x, y, z. I will always pass the same value, just to a different parameter. So I could do this:

```
if setting is x:
    package.someFunction(x=1)
elif setting is y:
    package.someFunction(y=1)
elif setting is z:
    package.someFunction(z=1)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it? Can I assign the parameter name to some variable pass it that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would build a dictionary with `setting` as the key and the static value as the value. This way, you don't have to do that awkward switching.

For example:

```
setting = 'x'
kwargs = {setting: 1}
package.someFunction(**kwargs)
```

Just change the `setting = 'x'` line to be however you're getting that setting. It just needs to equal the name of the argument in `package.someFunction` that you want to apply the value to.

Comment: So setting would just be `'x'` or `'z'`? That's great, thanks!

Comment: @Niel Exactly. You'd have `setting` be a string with the name of the argument.

Comment: You don't even need the variable for the argument; you can pass a `dict` literal: `package.someFunction(**{setting: 1})`.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, normally that's how I'd do it. I'm just breaking it down to make each step clearer.